# ASP.NET Core Controllers Route attribute inheritance and Abstract controllers actions - AmbiguousActionException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on ASP.NET Core Webapi project. I would like to implement some kind of Base/Abstract generic controller for all methods that are common for every controller (e.g. CRUD methods) and inherit this Controller in all other controllers. 
I attach example code below:

```
public abstract class BaseApiController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetAll() 
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public virtual IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public virtual IActionResult Insert(myModel model)
    {
        ...
    }
}


[Route("api/Student")]
public class StudentController : BaseApiController 
{
    // Inherited endpoints:
    // GetAll method is available on api/Student [GET]
    // GetById method is available on api/Student/{id} [GET]
    // Insert method is available on api/Student [POST]
    //
    // Additional endpoints:
    // ShowNotes is available on api/Student/{id}/ShowNotes [GET]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/ShowNotes")]
    public virtual IActionResult ShowNotes(int id) 
    {
        ...
    }
}

[Route("api/Teacher")]
public class TeacherController : BaseApiController 
{
    // Inherited endpoints:
    // GetAll method is available on api/Teacher [GET]
    // GetById method is available on api/Teacher/{id} [GET]
    // Insert method is available on api/Teacher [POST]
    //
    // Additional endpoints:
    // ShowHours is available on api/Teacher/{id}/ShowHours [GET]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}/ShowHours")]
    public virtual IActionResult ShowHours(int id) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have seen this kind of solution in .NET Framework WebApi, with additional custom RouteProvider, e.g.:

```
public class WebApiCustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory> GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>(inherit: true);
    }
}
```

Every time I try to reach Endpoint in derived controller I got AmbiguousActionException:

```
Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
XXX.WebApi.Controllers.CommonAppData.TeacherController.GetById
XXX.WebApi.Controllers.CommonAppData.StudentController.GetById
```

Is it possible to create such Base controller in .NET Core WebApi? 
How should I write it to reach Action Methods without declaring it explicitly in derived Controller?
How should I configure this kind of solution? Any additional configuration in Startup class?

Comment: Are there any problems with that in .NET Core WebApi?

Comment: Your code works fine in .NET Core WebAPI without any additional custom RouteProvider. Where is the problem?

Comment: Yes you can achieve this for CRUD operations and catching exceptions and logging. BaseController is helpful for corss-cutting cuncerns in your application. 
I would create a generic base controller ... public class BaseController<T> where T will be your model for Teacher and Student types.

Comment: Also, the routing in .net core is attribute based. There is no route.config file.

Comment: I edited the question :) 
I receive AmbiguousActionException for every derived endpoint. 
My Base controller is Generic, but for more "clear" question I skipped this part.

Comment: And again your code works fine! Or you didn't share all code or you have to remove `WebApiCustomDirectRouteProvider `.

Comment: See on this working code https://gist.github.com/Marusyk/64dacdcd93ab932e2a14aa50e410840b and try it to reproduce

Comment: if I remember correctly, i saw this problem when OpenApi / Swagger is active. But not sure. I think, there was something that swagger removes namespaces from types (can be disabled). But not sure...

Comment: Ok, the problem was with my controller. 
I had 2 controllers with really simillar names. By misspell, I added to them the same [Route] Attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As this topic is a good one so it worth and I explain how I did it. You can create a **Generic** Controller like this :

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class BaseController<TEntity> : Controller where TEntity : class, new()
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _db;
    
    public BaseController(YourDbContext db)
    {
        _db=db;
    }
    
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
    {
        var data= await _db.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
        return View(data);
    }
    
    public virtual IActionResult GetById(int id)
    {
        var data= await _db.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(e=>e.Id == id);
        return View(data);
    }
    .....
    
}
```

Then you can use it like this :

```
public class StudentController : BaseController<Student> 
{
}
```

Off course you can write it better with optional parameters something like this:

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>? predicate = null)
{
    var data= await _db.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    ....
}
```

Or even override every action in inherited controller as you like and adding necessary parameters to your actions

```
public override Task<IActionResult> Get(....
```

I hope enjoy it ;) and don't forget to **up Vote** .